# Disable touchpad hardware buttons

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I'd like to disable hardware buttons on the synaptic touchpad, but still be able to use the touchpad and "tap"-click on its surface. I don't find the related options in the output of `synclient -l`.

Note that I don't want to disable the touchpad completely. Only to make it ignore the hardware buttons, but still respond to taps.

Comment: What you get when you type `synclient -l` in terminal.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/bcgKwqyG

Comment: I have updated my answer,have a look at it.

Comment: My question is not how to disable it completely, only how to disable its hardware buttons.

Comment: This should be retagged with `synaptics`; `synaptic` (without the final `s`) is the graphical package manager that comes with Ubuntu, while Synaptics is a type of touchpad.

Comment: Agreed, sorry for typo.

Comment: There was a big thread on here recently where someone was trying to disable the touchpad while still being able to use the trackstick. If that's not possible then I doubt this is either; good luck though!

Comment: Yes, I am afraid this is hardware problem too.

Comment: @jetxee Are you still hunting for a solution on this one?

Comment: @jgbelacqua I learned not to press the broken button, but I didn't find if it is possible to disable hardware buttons in software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filed a bug against `gpointing-device-settings` [#793440](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpointing-device-settings/+bug/793440). It seems impossible to do what I want with the current version of the software. Question closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Disabling Touchpad:**

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type **gconf-editor** and click Run.

[image]

Navigate to desktop>gnome>peripherals>touchpad,in the right panel uncheck the entry **touchpad_enabled**.

[image]

Now your touchpad will be disabled.

To turn off touchpad completely install [gpointing-device-settings](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gpointing-device-settings) [image: Install gpointing-device-settings]. After installation you can access it under **System > Preferences > Touchpad**

**UPDATE:**

- If you want to use `synclient` then you have to edit your `xorg.conf` file.

  ```
  sudo -H gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
  ```
- See these [instructions to edit xorg.conf](http://paste.ubuntu.com/540610/)
- [Also See this tutorial on disabling touchpad.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10155078&postcount=1)
- [How to disable/enable touchpad in Ubuntu](http://www.linuxine.com/2008/06/how-to-disable-touchpad-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like not to disable the touchpad completely. Only to make it ignore the _hardware_ buttons, but still respond to taps.

Comment: I suggest you [file against gpointing-device-settings](http://pad.lv/fb/u/gpointing-device-settings); this doesn't seem to be currently possible.

Comment: Thank you, @poolie, I filed this as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpointing-device-settings/+bug/793440. I you wrote this as an answer, I'd be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**This will disable the hardware buttons and the "tap" feature, but you will be able to move the pointer:**

1) Create this file:

```
gedit ~/.Xmodmap
```

2) Paste this into it:

```
pointer = 0 0 0
```

3) Logout and log back in, or reboot, or run this:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

---

**To get it back to normal:**

1) Edit the file:

```
gedit ~/.Xmodmap
```

2) And change to:

```
pointer = default
```

3) Logout and log back in, or reboot, or run this:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

4) If this file doesn't have **anything** else, then you can delete it after step "3":

```
rm ~/.Xmodmap
```

Comment: Won't this disable mouse clicks altogether, regardless of origin?

Comment: :-/ You probably right, I will check that when I get to my computer (I'm on mobile now).

Comment: Were you able to check whether this worked?

Comment: Sorry. It disables the hardware buttons AND the touchpad tap. I am searching for a better solution.