# How to disable physical mouse buttons below touchpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I'd like to disable the two click buttons below my touchpad because the right one keeps activating randomly. I've read doc about synaptics and synclient, and using xmodmap as suggested in [Disable touchpad hardware buttons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16485/disable-touchpad-hardware-buttons) doesn't work because it also disables my usb mouse buttons.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Ok, as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156949/how-to-keep-the-touchpad-but-want-to-deactivate-the-buttons, it's possible to deactivate the hardware buttons in a laptop using `xinput`. The basic steps are the following:

1. Get the name (or id) of your touchpad

   ```
   xinput list
   ```
2. With that name (or id) you can disable you touchpad totally like this,

   ```
   xinput --disable 12
   ```

   being *12* the id of your touchpad, or you can disable only some buttons, using

   ```
   xinput list --long 12
   ```

   to get a map of the different buttons and then the option `--set-button-map` to remap them. For example,

   ```
   xinput --set-button-map 12 0 0 0 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
   ```

   disables the first three buttons in my touchpad, that is, left, center and right.

Comment: But how do you disable the button but keep "Tap to Click" so that you can tap with the touchpad but not the button?