# Tweaking touchpad decativation TIME when typing on 22.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 22.04

whenever I type, sometimes my hand touches touchpad and mouse goes to a random place and following digits are written in the wrong place.

In order to solve this I activated the "disable-while-typing" setting for the touchpad in org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad within dconf-editor.

Unfoertunately this is not really working all the times (while most of them does) and I was asking myself if there's a "delay" setting to further tweak the "sleep" of the touchpad after a keypress, but couldn't find any referral to this by googling around.

Also, I am not sure (I made some manual tests) if this "touch" fully depends just from the hand touching the touchpad or also touching the hardware mouse buttons: is there a way to also disable left+right hardware touchpad buttons when typing?

Thanks!
Pasha

Comment: Have a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/725607/how-to-disable-physical-mouse-buttons-below-touchpad

Comment: Thank you Will. I tried to fiddle with xinput and discovered that my button id was 10. Unfortunately a "xinput --get-button-map 10" complained as doesn't support running against Wayland.

Comment: sorry that didn't help. Another suggestion - not quite what you're asking but might be useful - there's very likely a keyboard shortcut to disable the mouse on your laptop - on mine it is fn-f9 (button has a crossed out touchpad on it). That disables buttons as well as touchpad - you can toggle it on and off pretty quickly. If it's not obvious from the keyboard, google your laptop model and you'll probably find the shortcut.

Comment: Yes, for sure there is, although the frequency of on/offs would be dramatically superior to the one of casual mistakes by touching the trackpad surface, maybe better educating my wrists to stay a bit upper :D